# How to call a class with required init from other class?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a class with:

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 }
```

I'm trying call this from other class:

```
 var myclass: MyClass!
var coder: NSCoder!


myclass = MyClass(coder)
```

How can pass paremeters correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: I can;t see anything wrong with your code. Please describe exactly what error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

In initializers parameter name is required by default, unless you use underscore to ignore it. In your example you create external parameter named coder so you need to call it, try:

```
myclass = MyClass(coder: coder)
```